# Dropping tables because of GET method?

Tags: post, get

I have simple question. I did GET form search to get ID of a show, so after code is executed, the url looks like this:

> ...show.php?showid=**inserted number**

So, is it possible to drop all tables only because I used GET method, and therefore, should I use POST?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL injection can occur from GET as well as POST requests. EDIT: It depends entirely on the code that processes the request.

Comment: I see, well it's seems I'll have to study more about that. Okay thank you, just wasn't sure, that's all.

Comment: This is the canonical explanation here on SO of how to prevent SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This is the canonical explanation here on SO of how to prevent SQL injection: [stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) –  Andy Lester Feb 13 at 23:12"

Thanks. I'm not sure how to post comment as an answer, but this satisfied me. I tried SQL injection into my table, but probably not related one:`' or '1'='1`

And I get this:

```
403
Forbidden
Access to this resource on the server is denied!
```

So that's all. Thank you guys once again.